How to sort by second value and match found sort by first value alphabetical - python
I have a scenario where i stuck not getting how do i need to implement.
I have string need to find count of each letter -> ('a',2). Sort by second value which is count and order by first if same count for other letter as well.
My code :
s = 'aabbbccde'
c = re.finditer(r'([\w])(\1*)',s)
lst = []

for i in c:
    lst.append((list(map(str,set(i.__getitem__(0))))[0] , len(i.__getitem__(0))))
    
var = sorted(
lst,
key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)

for i in sorted( (sorted(var,key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)) , key=lambda x:x[0])[:3]:
    print(i[0],i[1])

My output :
a 2
b 3
c 2

I am not getting as expected output :
b 3
a 2
c 2

Where i am going wrong in my code or is their any efficent way to do it ...

One question, you don't want to print the alphabet those counts are less than 2? Or in this case you just print top 3?

I think it will be easier with a dictionary, like this
s = 'aabbbccde'

# Step 1: Count the occurrences of each character
char_count = {}
for char in s:
    if char in char_count:  # if char in dictionary increment the count
        char_count[char] += 1
    else:
        char_count[char] = 1  # otherwise add the char and count 1

# Step 2: Convert the counts to a list of tuples
char_list = [(char, count) for char, count in char_count.items()]

# Step 3: Sort the list by count (descending) and character (ascending)
sorted_char_list = sorted(char_list, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))

# Print the results
for char, count in sorted_char_list:
    print(char, count)


-> why -x[1] given ... explain

The -x[1] in the sorting key is used to sort the counts in descending order.

Thank your code as helped to write code using different method. :)

You can also use reverse=True, instead of -x[1], both will work.

You mixed order or sorting, sorted first by number, then by character, and second sort took precedence.
Also, you didn't use reverse=True on second sort.
I modified last 2 lines, and it now apparently works Ok:
....
for i in sorted((sorted(var, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)), 
        key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:3]:
    print(i[0], i[1])

prints:
b 3
c 2
a 2


s = 'aabbbccde'
c = re.finditer(r'([\w])(\1*)',s)

for i in sorted(c, key=lambda i: len(i.group()), reverse=True):
    print(i.group()[0], len(i.group()))

Explanation
key=lambda i: len(i.group()), this will take the matches from the c and will sort them by the length of each of the group string

s = 'aabbbccde'
unique = list(set(s))    # Remove duplicate values using set and list
dct = {k:s.count(k) for k in unique}   # dict of key value pair of each letter & count

# Sort first by values in descending then by keys in ascending
sorted_dct = dict(sorted(dct.items(), key = lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])))

print(sorted_dct)

# Output : {'b': 3, 'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 1, 'e': 1}

